# Separating AWS CodePipeline Deployments for Main & Dev

Tags: git, continuous-deployment, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have set up an AWS CodePipeline for my project, which has two branches: `main` and `dev`. Each branch serves a different purpose, with `main` representing the production environment and `dev` representing the development environment. I am using AWS CodeDeploy as the deployment provider.

In my pipeline, I want to have distinct deployment configurations for each branch to avoid loading the same configuration from the appspec file onto the main server when merging changes from the dev branch.

Is there a way to configure AWS CodePipeline to use different appspec files, such as `appspec.dev.yml` for the dev branch and `appspec.prod.yml` for the main branch, during the deployment process? I want to ensure that changes made in the development environment don't unintentionally affect the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to accomplish this by using a rename operation during the build phase. Assuming that you're using AWS CodeBuild as part of your pipeline, you'd do that via an environment variable that is passed from CodePipeline as shown below.

[image]

Then, in CodeBuild's buildspec.yml, you can read the environment variable and apply the rename operation.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo "Pre-Build phase commands here..."
      - echo "Current branch is -> $BRANCH"
      - |
        if [ "$BRANCH" == "dev" ]; then
          mv appspec.dev.yml appspec.yml
        else
          mv appspec.prod.yml appspec.yml
        fi

  build:
    commands:
      - echo "Build phase commands here..."

artifacts:
  files: appspec.yml
```

AFAIK there's no easy way to do this without using environment variables as the branch name cannot be read easily from within CodeBuild using a `git` command for example. Reason being that CodeBuild uses a detached worktree. But the solution above should be simple and straightforward enough.